# Linear combination to recover particular data entry from denoised data?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, signal-processing

Let $\mathbf{x} = [x_1,  x_2, x_3]^t$ the 'data' where $x_1$ is considered to be 'noise', $M$ a $3\times 3$-matrix with full rank, and $\mathbf{y} = M\mathbf{x}$ the obserced mixture.

Let $m^-_i$ denote the $i^\text{th}$ row of the inverse $M^-$ such that $m^-_i\mathbf{y} = x_i$.

Let $N$ be a $2 \times 3$-matrix whose rows span the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by $m^-_1$ (not necessarily consisting of $m^-_2, m^-_3$), i.e. the 'noise' $x_1$ is being neglected.

(When) Is it possible to find a vector $\mathbf{p} = [p_1, p_2]$ such that $\mathbf{p}N\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{p}NM\mathbf{x} = x_2$?

If, how does $\mathbf{p}$ relate to $m^-_2$?

---

Attempts

Ideally it must hold that
$\mathbf{p}NM\mathbf{x} = m^-_2M\mathbf{x}$, hence $\mathbf{p}N=m^-_2$, which is a system of 3 equations and 2 unknowns, hence overdetermined and has no solution in general.

This somehow seems odd, as it intuitively should still be possible to get $x_2$ since only $x_1$ has been neglected..where am I fool messing up things?

---

Example

$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ such that $\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1+x_2+x_3 \\ x_2+x_3 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $m^-_2 = [0, 1, -1]$.

Let $N = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ such that $N\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2+2x_3 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$ from which we cannot obtain $x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why things go wrong is that your matrix $M$ is not orthogogonal.

Let's look at your example a bit more closely: First of all the conclusion you draw in the end should probably be that we cannot obtain $x_1$ since here $x_2$ plays the role of your noise. What you do see in this example is that if you take the matrix $N$ you do not neglect $x_2$, as it still shows up in $Ny$. This is because taking the orthogonal complement of your vector $m_\bar 2 = [0, 1, -1]$ will not get rid of this component. However, if your measurement matrix $M$ was orthogonal this would work but then the vectors $m_\bar 1, m_\bar 3$ would span the orthogonal complement of $m_\bar 2$ anyways.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Typo corrected - thanks. True, so if $M$ is orthogonal things work out. Intuitively this seems odd to me, as after removal of the 'noise' we should still be able to recover the things that we in principle could have recovered before...

Comment: Well, the point is that you do not really remove the noise by measuring with the orthogonal complement of the 'noise measurement'. Since $M$ is not orthogonal in general your matrix $N$ has an image that might contain part of the subspace you labeled as noise. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So even if one knows how to obtain the noise, one cannot/does not remove the noise by simply looking at the complement. One can remove one dimension then, that is solely noise. The noise from the other dimensions cannot be really removed?

Comment: Well, it can be removed completely using the inverse matrix rows. Consider the projection $P = [[0,0,0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]$, then the following computation allows to remove the noise from a vector $y$: $\bar y = MPM^{-1}y$. If you analyze this equation you realize that you can get rid of rows/colums in the matrices as they just contain zeros.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was imprecise. I meant if one only knows $m^-_2$ but not all of $M^-$ the noise cannot be removed, although one knows how to get the sole 'noise' from y.

Comment: I think I don't understand your comment: if you know $m_\bar 2$ then you can recover $x_2$ and only $x_2$ from any signal $y$